# CLR equivalent to MFC CStringList

Tags: mfc, clr, visual-c++

Hey. I'm trying to get this code http://www.codeguru.com/Cpp/W-P/files/inifiles/article.php/c4455/#more to compile under a CLR WinForms app I'm making.
But what is the right syntax? A CString under CLR is to be written System::String but what about CStringList? (I figure it's a string array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by CLR equivalent?

If you mean plain C# then this will do:

```
string[] arr = new string[size];
```

or:

```
List<String> list = new List<String>();
```

If you mean C++/CLI by CLR equivalent then something like this should work:

```
array<String^>^ arr = gcnew array<String^>(size);
```

or:

```
List<String^>^ list = gcnew List<String^>^();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use one of the types from `System.Collections.Generic`, for example [System.Collections.Generic.List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

There is a simple example at the bottom of that page.

Answer (score 0):

[StringCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection.aspx) for instance,
or

```
List<String>
```